# how to get data from table when pagination is used using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have table in which only 10 data are display on first page and then 11th data goes to second page. How do you get the table data when pagination is used using selenium webdriver .

Comment: trying to help with grammar.  Not a very good question though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by clicking on page 2 link. When browser goes to second page, then you can extract data from 2nd page.

Comment: can i know the length of table including pagination.how to check pagination is there or not

Comment: I got one link for pagination i selenium but not understood it . link http://seleniumhome.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-can-we-automate-pagination-using.html  if any can understand this code please  explain

Comment: The programs find all the elements having the specified xpath, iterate for every element found and click on them else print 'no pagination'. It also wrongly assumes that every pagination webelement has a class 'nav-pages'.

Comment: @vnnogile Example given in the blog are for that particular example. For your case you have to find x-path yourself. you will find a common class or any other element that you can iterate over.

Comment: can you share the page url. and the code u have written.

Comment: hi Sandeep,I first get size of Page using this code WebElement pagination = driver.findElement(By
      .id("requisitionsTable_paginate"));
    List<WebElement> pagination_count = pagination.findElements(By
      .xpath("//*[@id='requisitionsTable_paginate']/ul/li"));
    System.out.println("No. of page in table: " + pagination_count.size());